# How to pull AWS tag value from host_vars with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I would like to pull values from AWS EC2 tags via Ansible.  This works:

```
{{ hostvars[host]['ec2_private_ip_address'] }}
```

and will return the IP address.  So, I'm getting EC2 data.  However, I have a tag called app on my EC2 instances with values like Cassandra or PostGres, and I need to find out for each host I'm currently processing what app is associated with that post.  Any ideas of how to grab the value of an EC2 tag?

Comment: I presume that Ansible hostvars is populated from the EC2 instance metadata service. The metadata service does not know the EC2 tags so they're not available. You need to get them dynamically via the EC2 API (DescribeInstances). Believe that there's an EC2 inventory plugin for Ansible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ec2_tag_xxx'] where xxx is the tag in question

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is no longer working for me, but led me to this which does work now.

```
{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].tags.<tagKey>}}
```